# Variable given same address as the pointer that is pointing to it

Tags: c++

I am busy learning about pointers and playing around a bit with different results. 
While doing this I noticed that when I declare a variable and obtain its address, I get one value. But then when I declare a pointer that points to that variable, I get a different address for that same variable. And I also saw that this new address given to the variable was actually the address of the pointer itself(after checking). How can this be?

Just to be clear; I declared `int a` and then `int *p` to point to `a`. The address for `a` was `0x22ff2c` (originally before declaring pointer), and the address for the pointer `p` was `0x22ff28`. The new address for `a` after I declared the pointer was also `0x22ff28`, the same as the address of the pointer itself.

I looked around on the net and here on SO to find some answers, but didn't really get what I needed. Here as some links which came close. This [SO Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329399/is-a-pointer-variable-also-assigned-a-memory-address) touches on the subject, but doesn't tell me what I don't already know. This other one [SO Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21808324/c-the-value-that-the-pointer-is-pointing-to-changes) seems similar to what I am asking, but it's way too advanced and makes my head spin.

A simple explanation would be appreciated as I am still very new to C++, thank you.

### Code 1

```
int main()


{

int a = 1;
std::cout << "Address1: " << &a;
return 0;
}
```

### output of code 1 ##

> Address1: 0x22ff2c

### code 2

```
int a = 1;
int *p;
p = &a;
std::cout << "Address1: " << p;
return 0;
```

### output of code 2

> Address1: 0x22ff28

### code 3

```
int a = 1;
int *p;
p = &a;
std::cout << "Address1: " << p << "\n" << "Address2: " << &a;
return 0;
```

### output of code 3

> Address1: 0x22ff28
>
> Address2: 0x22ff28

### code 4

```
int a =1;
int *p;
p = &a;
std::cout << "Address1: " << &p;
```

### output of code 4

> Address1: 0x22ff28

Comment: in your last code, the addresses are the same, so what are you talking about?

Comment: You are only ever outputting the VALUE of 'p': count ... << p; If you want the ADDRESS of 'p', use count << &p. Did I misunderstand what you're asking?

Comment: `operator<<` is overloaded for pointer types.

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Post the text of the code using the formatting functions stackoverflow.com provides. Ditto for the output.

Comment: @Walter That's the problem. I got the same address. In the first case I got one address for "a". Then I got a different address for "a" after using "p" to point at it. And that second address I got was the same address as the pointer itself. I checked this using &p to get the pointer's address.

Comment: @mrunion I DID use &p to get the address of of p too. That's why I said in my question that I checked to see what the address of p is to verify.

Comment: @remyabel I have no idea what you just said haha

Comment: @Steve Alright. Will do so in future. But is there any specific reason why not? Since I thought the images tab on SO was meant to be used to upload pics of code, outputs, etc.

Comment: Can you post the program and output you are having trouble with?

Comment: (just in case:  you can't draw any comparison between the addresses reported by two different programs, you have to write a single program that does all the outputting)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Alright. i will edit my question now with the different codes and results. And yes, I did do different runs. Maybe that is where the problem set in.

Comment: @AshleyPieterse you're still showing 4 separate programs (3 of which only display one output) and you haven't said what you think is strange about those. Make one single program that demonstrates everything you don't understand

Comment: @MattMcNabb You were right. I had to put them all in one program. Which I did now. I got &a = 0x22ff2c ; p = 0x22ff2c ; &p = 0x22ff28. That makes a whole lot more sense now. It seems I just misunderstood how the compiler works on separate runs as opposed to one single run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `&a == p`. You are **not** printing the pointer's address. For that print `&p` instead of `p`. You will likely get a different address.

Try this :

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   int a = 3 ;
   int *p = &a ;
   std::cout << &a << "\n" << p << "\n" << &p ;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned to another user below, I DID use &p to check the address of the pointer and got the same address as that of "a".

Comment: Where is the `&p` code ? Please post the code and output then.

Comment: I am having the same discussion with someone else above. The code is exactly as that in the pics. Only difference is that I used &p as std::cout. And I got the same address for &p as for p.

Comment: ^Print both `&p` and `p` side by side. Compare the results and post the output.

Comment: I did what you said now, and got these results:  I got &a = 0x22ff2c ; p = 0x22ff2c ; &p = 0x22ff28. That makes much more sense. I think I just misunderstood how compilers work on different runs as opposed to one single run. I will choose your answer since it showed what I actually should have done right from the start. Thanks for your patience on this, and also for "pointing" me in the right direction, Akash.  :)

Answer (score 0):

`0x22ff28` is not address of the pointer but of the target the pointer is pointing to. Which is `a`. The address of the pointer is `&p`.

Comment: But that is the problem. I DID use &p to check the address of the pointer and I got 0x22ff28, which is the same address as that of "a".

Comment: In your code (the last image) you use `p`, not `&p`. Try using `&p` and you would get a different address.

Comment: Well, I used "p" in that case to show that the address has now changed. I used &p afterwards and saw it is the same address as p. I didn't post a pic of the output for "&p", but I can assure you I got the same address as for "p" and "a". And this is what confuses me.

Comment: Please post the code you used. Note that different runs of the program may have different addresses, even so that `&a` in one will be the same as `&p` in the other.

Comment: Well, I used exactly the same code as in the images. The only difference was that for the std::cout I used "&p" instead of "p" and "a". Speaking about different runs; the strange thing is that I get the same address values for every single run. Even when closing code::blocks(which I am using) and restarting it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's part of what I think you're trying to ask: First `a` had address 0x22ff2c, then the program was changed to have variable `p` and after that `a` has a different address. Why?

The answer is, the compiler made different choices when building the second program than it did when build the first. After all, they're *different* programs.

The actual memory addresses used by two different programs (even if they are mostly similar) may be different for various reasons. They're not really comparable. (And when you get into more complex and less predictable situations, especially using dynamic allocation, then the memory addresses used by different invocations of the same program can be different.)

Now, for another part of your question:

> The new address for "a" after I declared the pointer was also 0x22ff28, the same as the address of the pointer itself.

In the code you've shown, you're only ever examining the address that `p` contains, not the address that `p` itself lives at. If you try outputting `&p` then you'll see where it is and find that it is indeed different than `&a`.

Comment: Yes. You understand my question correctly. And I think you are right about the different programs issue. However, I did output &p, and got the same result. I have edited my question with all the code and results I got.